# How to make a service sticky in memory even if activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, service, vitamio

I have a mediaplayer which I implemented it inside service and I call startSerivce() from an activity in my android app, also I show a notification from my service to keep user updated.

Here is the problem :
When I press back button and close activity and turn of the mobile's screen the musicplayer service will play for 1~2 minutes then it will close the service and stops the music.

my activity code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//some code above
Intent intentMPLS = new Intent(Splash.this, MediaPlayerLocalService.class);
    startService(intentMPLS);
    //some code below
}
```

and inside my serivce I have following for startForground :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

startForeground(PlayerNotification.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                PlayerNotification.getInstance(this, global).createServiceNotification(true));
//The PlayerNotification is cusotmized class to show notification
return START_STICKY;
}
```

How can I prevent android to kill my service?

note : my MediaPlayer is Vitamio just in case if Vitamio is the problem.

Comment: "service will play for 1~2 minutes then it will close the service and stops the music" -- more likely, the device simply went into sleep mode.

Comment: how can I prevent phone to go to that state?

Answer (score 1):

add permission in manifest:
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

and your onStartCommand method should look like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

startForeground(PlayerNotification.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                PlayerNotification.getInstance(this, global).createServiceNotification(true));
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
//The PlayerNotification is cusotmized class to show notification
return START_STICKY;
}
```

more on
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu